# Filtering on list produces more data than it should

Tags: excel, list, filter

So I am filtering a sheet based on a list that I import containing names.  In the list of imported names is the name Williams.  When I do the filter, it returns not only Williams, but Williamsen and Williamson.  How do I stop that?  I need exact only matches.  Here is my code:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Range("D17:D" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("J1:J16"), Unique:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because Excel pads out the end of your search terms with a catch-all * wildcard character, meaning you don't get an exact search. There are two ways to get Excel to do an exact search.

**Method one:** 
First, put as equals sign in front of your criteria terms. e.g. =Michael Williams. Note that you can't type that *directly* into the cell, because Excel of course thinks that anything starting with an equals sign is a formula, and so tries to evaluate it as a formula, and you get a #NAME? error. So you either need to prefix it with the ' apostrophe character (which tells Excel not to try and interpret the formula i.e. '=Michael Williams) or  you need to write a formula that returns =Michael Willams as text when evaluated (by using the general formula pattern ="=Michael Williams").

**Method Two**
Pad out your original surname list with a trailing space so that "Williams" becomes "Williams " and "Williamsen" becomes "Williamsen ". Then pad out your search terms too. After that, the search term of "Williams " will not match terms such as "Williamsen ".

Here's a demonstration of this in action. First, let's try it without the padding:

[image]

As you can see below, this incorrectly matched both Williams and Williamson:

[image]

Now, let's try it after padding both the Filter Criteria and the Data with spaces. (Note that in the below screenshot I have added a space at the beginning two. This isn't actually necessary):

[image]

As you can see, this time it works just fine:

[image]

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't work.  Also tried using (in the List Criteria) '=Williams - that results in 0 results.

Comment: It works for me. Can you post a screenshot or share more of the code that you tried?

Comment: After doing my last bit of filtering, I copy all data and paste into a new sheet within the workbook, then create 16 blank rows above all the data.  Then I paste a column of data, 16 rows long, into J1.  The data in J1-J16 is code, so I then convert it to values so it ends up being a list of names with a header (j1) that matches a header in the data fields below.  Then I run the code above in the original post.  

I have padded the name Michael Williams in the criteria list (J1-16) on both ends, and on just the back end, but it eliminates ALL williams results.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot? Using dummy data is fine.

Comment: Can you select the "Michael Williams" entry from the Criteria range in column J and take a screenshot of the formula bar, and then do the same with the "Michael Williams" entry in the data source from column D?

Comment: https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AAA6QZRFzCFevISBaieV72GQFzPBNerAiJnDzNIkD3JxeA/12/713728028/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Excel1.PNG/ELSHlPEFGAcgBygH/gr7b_a1hSgApHBW4U_QTbcYudBCYU-J2VeXE_jW6sg4?size=1280x960&size_mode=3

Comment: https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAC0NWo1fpJBWDlnb1TeGDeqbggDJWPw-UBSJF4WGg74Eg/12/713728028/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Excel2.PNG/ELSHlPEFGAcgBygH/NFHeSWaoN0Ze5Yy12aXmOLUk1aCMY0Dty6kFG-eiO34?size=1280x960&size_mode=3

Comment: I can't access these. Can you check you have shared these publicly?

Comment: Try this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/il32tx51ffj7vq2/%23photos-3.dropbox.com.url?dl=0

Comment: That didn't work.  Here is the first one:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/il32tx51ffj7vq2/%23photos-3.dropbox.com.url?dl=0

Comment: And the second
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlo0erbtf5irl1t/Excel1.PNG?dl=0

Comment: That first one's still not working for me. Also, can you point a LEN function at each cell, and confirm that you get the same number back? And also try another formula =[first reference] = [second reference] where [first reference] is the cell in the criteria range containing the Michael Williams entry, and [second reference]  is the cell from the range to be filtered containing his name. (I'm just checking to see if it's something like a non printing character that is screwing things up)

Comment: The LEN results in 16 in both cases, which is correct.  I'm not following you on the other change.  I'm very new, don't know how to code, just recording macros then slamming them all together into one master.

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes here. I originally suggested padding out the names in both the criteria range (Column J)  and the range you're running the advanced filter on (Column D) with trailing and leading spaces. That way, "Williams[space]" would not match "Williamsen[space]. But if these were in fact padded with extra spaces the length of the " Michael Williams " entries in both of them would be 18, not 16.

Comment: See my amended answer above, showing what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah!  Got it!  But geesh I can't believe there isn't just an "exact" function.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually it does have an exact function, but I forgot about it and gave you an alternative approach. For the Exact Match, your criteria terms must have equal sign at the start, e.g. =Michael Williams.  But you can't type that directly into the cell, because Excel tries to evaluate it as a formula, and you get a #NAME? error. So you need to prefix it with a ' which tells Excel not to try and interpret the formula i.e. '=Michael Williams. Or you can also actually enter it as a formula that return a text string using ="=Michael Williams".

Comment: Glad to have helped. Can you please accept my answer? I've amended my answer to include the syntax for the Exact Match method.

Comment: I tried that '=Michael Williams before I wrote this question and could not get it to work.  It kept returning a blank sheet.  But anyway, the padding worked and is now part of the macro.  Thanks again!